# How to force execution of next function

Tags: python, twitter

I am attempting execute multiple functions defined by the twitterbot library. I need the code to execute one function, then the next, and then the next, or in a random order. The function, however, is designed to run in a loop.

I rather stay away from editing the actual library, so I am looking for a solution that will allow me to execute the function just once, continue on to the next and loop from the top.

Is there a way in Python to do this?

```
from TwitterFollowBot import TwitterBot

my_bot = TwitterBot()
my_bot.sync_follows()

# Start of loop

my_bot.auto_fav("@asco", count=1000) 
# The above function persists to execute without continuing down
# Need bottom functions to also execute.
my_bot.auto_fav("ATSO", count=1000)
my_bot.auto_fav("BCY3", count=1000)
my_bot.auto_fav("ESIO", count=1000)

# End of loop
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand what exactly you want to execute, how often, and in what order.

Comment: @orlp I have a buffer set up for frequency, so I would just like to limit the execution of the function so that the next function with "ATSO" also gets executed. Currently (at)asco just loops over and over without executing the next function.

Comment: I wrote up an answer before you edited your question. What do you mean by "`above function persists to run without continuing down`". Is that what is happening or is that what you want it to do?

Comment: Thank you for your help @Farhan.K I would like the function to continue executing the other functions which are my_bot.auto_fav(...), however it persists to execute only the top one.

Comment: You could look into threading or multiprocessing. If that is something you want I could update my answer

Comment: @Farhan.K Yes please. Familiarizing myself with the process now.

Comment: I will edit it further when I have time. Right now you can use it as an example and try to use the same thing in your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the reference to the functions in a list then use `random.shuffle`. And you can use `threading.Thread` to run all of your functions. I am using `time.sleep` and `for` just as an example to illustrate how each thread is being executed even though the `for` loop isn't finished:

```
import random
import time
from threading import Thread

def a():
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(1)
def b():
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(2)
def c():
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(3)
def d():
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(4)
def e():
    for i in range(10000):
        print(i)
        time.sleep(5)

listOfFunctions = [a, b, c, d, e]
random.shuffle(listOfFunctions)


for i in listOfFunctions:
    Thread(target = i).start() # Use args=(your args) if you want to run each function with arguments
```